# Connection to PSQL database using Python

Tags: python, database-connection, psql

Look at the commands below for creating a table in PSQL using Python. After connection.close() is there any command to open the connection or fetch the connection to database again so that we need not write the whole commands to fetch connection and can easily alter the data in the table created??

```
import psycopg2


try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(database = "staff", user = "XYZ", password = "python", host = "localhost", port = "5432")
    
except psycopg2.Error as err:
    print("An error was generated!")
    
else:
    print("Connection to database was successful!")
    
cursor = connection.cursor()
 
cursor.execute('''create table mystaff.employees
      (id int primary key not null,
       first_name varchar(25) not null,
       last_name varchar(25) not null,
       department varchar(25) not null,
       phone varchar(25),
       address varchar(50),
       salary int);''')
       
connection.commit()
 
connection.close()
```

Comment: If you want to reuse the connection, simply do not call `connection.close()` at the end of the script. The function call that opens a connection is already in there: `psycopg2.connect()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you close a connection to a database, that connection object does not connect to the database anymore. You will have to reconnect to the database with

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(database = "staff", user = "XYZ", password = "python", host = "localhost", port = "5432")
```

Alternatively, you can do what you need to do, only closing the connection when you are done interacting with the database.

Comment: This didn't work. Need to find a way to gain the connection without again writing those commands for connection.

Comment: @AakarshAnubhav could you clarify the context of your code? putting all your necessary code in between connection.commit() and connection.close() should not require you to reconnect. Could you explain any specific reasons you are closing the connection while you have more to interact with the database.

Comment: I got the point. I will simply close the connection only when I am done with interacting with the database.